# How do you handle serialized edit fields in an Active Admin resource?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have a model, `Domain`, which has a text field, `names`.

```
> rails g model Domain names:text
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20111117233221_create_domains.rb
  create    app/models/domain.rb
> rake db:migrate
==  CreateDomains: migrating ==================================================
-- create_table(:domains)
   -> 0.0015s
==  CreateDomains: migrated (0.0066s) =========================================
```

I set this field as **serialized** into an array in the model.

```
# app/models/domain.rb
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :names, Array
end
```

Create the ActiveAdmin resource for this model

```
> rails g active_admin:resource Domain
    create  app/admin/domains.rb
```

then, in the app/admin/domains.rb, I setup the various blocks to handle the serialized field as such

```
# app/admin/domains.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Domain do

  index do
    id_column
    column :names do |domain|
      "#{domain.names.join( ", " ) unless domain.names.nil?}"
    end
    default_actions
  end

  show do |domain|
    attributes_table do
      row :names do
        "#{domain.names.join( ", " ) unless domain.names.nil?}"
      end
    end
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Domain" do
      f.input :names
    end
    f.buttons
  end

  # before we save, take the param[:domain][:name] parameter,
  # split and save it to our array
  before_save do |domain|
    domain.names = params[:domain][:names].split(",") unless params[:domain].nil? or params[:domain][:names].nil?
  end
end
```

Nearly everything works great -- my names are displayed as comma separated in the index and show views. When I update a record with my names field set to "a,b,c", the before_save works to turn that into an array that is then saved via the ActiveRecord serialize.

What I can not solve is how to make the edit form put in a comma-separated list into the text field. I tried using a partial and using formtastic syntax directly as well as trying to make it work via the active_admin DLS syntax. Does anyone know how to make this work?

**Specifically, if I have the following array saved in my domain.names field:**

```
# array of names saved in the domain active_record
domain.names = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

**how to change:**

```
      form do |f|
        f.inputs "Domain" do
          f.input :names
        end
        f.buttons
      end
```

**so that when the `edit` form is loaded, in the text field instead of seeing `abc`, you see `a,b,c`.**

Comment: Why don't you use attr_setter and attr_getter in your model, and implement conversion string <=> Array. You can handle it in there and i BET you will need it in some other parts of your application

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is a summary of how I handled this situation. I added an accessor to the model which can turn the Array into a string joined by a linefeed and split it back to an Array.

```
# app/models/domain.rb
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize       :names, Array
  attr_accessor   :names_raw

  def names_raw
    self.names.join("\n") unless self.names.nil?
  end

  def names_raw=(values)
    self.names = []
    self.names=values.split("\n")
  end
end
```

then, in my admin resource for domain, instead of using the `:names` field, I used the `:names_raw` field. setting this value would save the names Array with the new values.

```
# app/admin/domains.rb
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Domain" do
    f.input :names_raw, :as => :text
  end
  f.buttons
end
```

Comment: Nice idea. Some minor fixes: `attr_accessor` should not be there, and `value` should be renamed to `values`.

Comment: You should split using `/[\r\n]+/`, otherwise on OSX the `\r` is not stripped

Comment: You don't need this line
```attr_accessor   :names_raw```

Comment: That's a wonderful suggestion!
I also clean up the input with squish:
... values.split("\n").map { |row| row.squish }

Comment: This is a good start, but you need to modify the attribute once you click "update" in ActiveAdmin using controller do def update <code here to modify serialize data to conform the format> end end

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on this question looking for something to have access to a serialized `Hash`'s YAML. I used this solution on Rails 3.2:

```
def target_raw
  @attributes['target'].serialized_value
end

def target_raw=(new_value)
  @attributes['target'].state = :serialized
  @attributes['target'].value = new_value
end
```