# How to save array in Active Admin Rails 4?

Tags: arrays, model, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, ruby-2.0

I am using Active Admin in Rails 4. In my model i have one field which is an Postgres array type when i am creating the object it is passing in background but it is not saving to the database. So what i need to do to save the array field in database through Active Admin.

Thanks

Comment: array type? which database server are you using?

Comment: yes, Postgres server 9.1

Comment: Excuse me, Have read my question properly??? I am trying to save it through active admin.

Comment: aaah, no. i did not read that properly. but never the less, some googling reveals that this does not seem to be supported right now: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2064

Answer (score 17):

You have hack stuff since active admin doesn't support it out of the box, it seems.

Though this answer is old, it works: [How do you handle serialized edit fields in an Active Admin resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176104/how-do-you-handle-serialized-edit-fields-in-an-active-admin-resource)

> Here is a summary of how I handled this situation. I added an accessor to the model which can turn the Array into a string joined by a linefeed and split it back to an Array.

```
# app/models/domain.rb
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize       :names, Array
  attr_accessor   :names_raw

  def names_raw
    self.names.join("\n") unless self.names.nil?
  end

  def names_raw=(values)
    self.names = []
    self.names=values.split("\n")
  end
end
```

> then, in my admin resource for domain, instead of using the :names field, I used the :names_raw field. setting this value would save the names Array with the new values.

```
# app/admin/domains.rb
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Domain" do
    f.input :names_raw, :as => :text
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Comment: [New Version] Just an update for helping fellow follks, with active records >=4.1 and native Array fields(i.e Database which supports Array columns) do not use serialize. Reference https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29498

Answer (score 5):

Here's a similar but even simpler take on a solution if you don't need a fancy UI for the admin.

```
# app/model/thing.rb
def some_array_column= items
  if items.is_a? String
    super items.split(" ")
  else
    super items
  end
end
```

And

```
# app/admin/thing.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Thing do
  index do
    column "Things" { |t| (t.some_array_column || []).join(" ") }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple hack I found :

As Postgres treats arrays as `text` you can keep the default input for it and just parse the params as if it was some `json`.

```
# app/admin/model.rb

controller do
  def update
    params[:model][:array_attribute] = JSON.parse params[:model][:array_attribute]
    super
  end
end
```

**Tips**: make your array attribute default to `[]` so your input will already be filled with an empty array. You can also customize your input as if it was json for a better edtiting experience see https://github.com/udacity/activeadmin_json_editor

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution which can be used, if you not need some fancy form for editing

Write a Setter method module which can be used on any model

```
module StringToArrayValueSetter
  def string_to_array_setter(*column_names)
    column_names.each do |column_name|
      define_method("#{column_name}=") do |val|
        value = val.is_a?(String) ? YAML.load(val) : val 
        super value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Extend the setter method to your model

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
   extend StringToArrayValueSetter
   string_to_array_setter :column1, :column2
end
```

make your array column default to `[]`, it will be always filled by an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Here's what my solution looks like:

**My Migration**:

```
  def change
    add_column :agency_services, :required_fields, :string, array: true, default: []
  end
```

**Active Admin Resource Model:**

```
  permit_params [required_fields: []]

  controller do
    def update
      params[:agency_service][:required_fields] = params[:agency_service][:required_fields].split(' ')
      super
    end
  end
```

**And how I format each individual item meant to be set as an array:**

`occupation home_number work_number`

afterwards this ends up translating into this:

`[occupation, home_number, work_number]`

Since I set the `String.split(' ')` function to a blank space, it separates the items to be arrayed by spaces but you can use a comma too...